# What has Biden's presidency done to improve US relations with Pakistan?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, pakistan, joe-biden

Biden is sometimes quoted (e.g. [here](https://networks.h-net.org/node/28443/reviews/4109030/elias-coll-directorate-s-cia-and-americas-secret-wars-afghanistan-and) or [here](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2018/03/the-pakistan-trap/550895/)) for this quip to (former Afghan president) Karzai that

> Pakistan is fifty times more important than Afghanistan for the United States.

I mean besides perhaps letting ISI "have their way" in Afghanistan, **what has Biden done (since being elected POTUS) to improve US relations with Pakistan?**

During the Obama presidency, Biden was often at odds with Secretary of State Clinton, and even with Obama himself at times on foreign intervention-policy matters. Biden's disagreements with Clinton are the more clearly documented ones; these also included [Syria, Iraq, and Lybia](http://web.archive.org/web/20161229102640/https://foreignpolicy.com/2015/10/21/will-biden-haunt-hillarys-presidential-campaign/). Clinton has also openly criticized Biden on his Afghanistan policy [this spring](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-56966473). So basically this is why I'm asking what has Biden done since he's become commander in chief to improve relations with Pakistan, and not before when he was just VP, even though the quip I quoted above dates from that era.

I also recall now that there was an article in the Pakistani press [in January 2021](https://www.dawn.com/news/1602541) that the US intended to rebuild military ties/assistance to Pakistan (under Biden). On the other hand, the Indian press in particular [likes](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/us-pak-ties-amid-changes-in-afghanistan/article35947962.ece) to bring up [the issue](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/pakistan/not-waiting-for-bidens-call-imran-khan/articleshow/85275992.cms) that PM Khan is allegedly pissed off that Biden has never called Khan since being elected. So (to repeat the question) what steps has the US taken to improve relations with Pakistan, since Joe Biden's inauguration as POTUS?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not much was done to improve relations, the opposite was the case as can be read in [this article by the guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/oct/10/biden-administration-delivers-brusque-message-to-pakistan). Acording to the article Biden administration has even downgraded the bilateral relationship.

Comment: Well that was 10 months ago, when Khan was still PM.

Comment: More recently I read that "Biden administration approves upgrade of Pakistan’s F-16 fighter aircraft in $450-million deal." FWTW https://theprint.in/defence/biden-administration-approves-upgrade-of-pakistans-f-16-fighter-aircraft-in-450-million-deal/1120715/ Although in the fine print, the deal isn't that amazing for Pakistan (no new toys).